# "Секретное" фото с камеры iPhone?

Tags: photo, ios9

Можно ли получить изображение с камеры телефона (при наличии разрешения пользователя на использование камеры) не выводя при этом никаких диалогов/превью (например, UIImagePickerController)?

т.е. простыми словами - в определенный момент (при нажатии на кнопку или программно) обратились к камере и получили UIImage для дальнейшей обработки, на экране при этом интефейс никак не поменялся.

Если подобное возможно, можно ссылку на какой-ть пример с аналогичной/похожей функциональностью?

Comment: после того как пользователь разрешил приложению использовать камеру никаких ограничений программа больше не испытывает, может осуществлять съемку в том числе скрытно (если на устройстве не предусмотрен аппаратный индикатор включенного режима экспозиции). Вопрос только что с этим делать дальше - по сети отправить - трафик атомный встанет, делать какой-то анализ... может быть, чтобы потом раз в день каких-то 100 килобайт отправить кому-то :)

Comment: на iphon'ах/ipad'ах "предусмотрен аппаратный индикатор включенного режима экспозиции"? или это абстрактный коммент?

Comment: его там нет - по крайне мере на моем iPad Air 2 :-) Но может быть на других моделях, я не проверял все :-) Или на будущих моделях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример получения фото без использования UIImagePickerController:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface TestViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *tmpImageView;

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self p_configureSecretCamera];
}

#pragma mark - Class API

- (void)takePhoto {
    [self p_takeSecretPhoto];
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

- (void)p_configureSecretCamera {
    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [self.session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];

    if ([self.session canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
        [self.session addInput:deviceInput];
    }

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
    [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    self.stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [self.stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [self.session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];
    [self.session startRunning];
}

- (void)p_takeSecretPhoto {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.stillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort * port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    [self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            self.tmpImageView.image = image; // !!!:

            // TODO:
            // 1. убрать звук затвора камеры при фотографировании
            // 2. настроить выбор камеры (фронт/бэк)
            // 3. отключить вспышку
        }
    }];
}
```

для полностью "секретного" фото нужно еще убрать звук "затвора камеры":
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23758876
и отключить вспышку